# GEE Plotting Legends - automatic assignment of colors and values

Tags: google-earth-engine, legend, google-earth-engine-python-api

I have added the legend in the map but I have hard-coded the values and the colors like this:

```
ldict = {'-1.0 - 0.0':'#FFFF00', 
             '0.0 - 0.3': '#c7d270',
             '0.3 - 0.5': '#81B622',
             '0.5 - 0.7': '#008631',
             '0.7 - 1.0': '#3D550C'}

Map.add_legend(legend_titles="NDVI Values" ,legend_dict=ldict, position='bottomleft')
```

In NDVI there exists a gradient of colors but assigning the colors and the values manually seems a bit unreasonable. So, a gradient of colors should be assigned to the values.

Is there any way we can make this automatic? For example, the range of the values and the colors in the legend should be displayed by getting the values and the colors from the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous Legends (**Color Maps**) are available in GEE which creates an effect of the gradient. I have followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4rqTp6ru9k) tutorial and [this](https://geemap.org/notebooks/49_colorbar/) link. and it worked really well.

**Code:**

```
vis = {
    'min': -1.0,
    'max': 1.0,
    'palette': ['#FFFF00', '#c7d270','#81B622', '#008631', '#3D550C']}
Map.add_colorbar(vis, label ="NDVI", layer_name="NDVI")
Map
```

Comment: How would this work for categorical values of feature collections?

Comment: @PhilippR In this [link](https://geemap.org/notebooks/49_colorbar/#categorical-colorbar) there is an example of a categorical color bar as well.

Comment: True but for images and not feature collections.